# asterisk dialplan, how to use includes in contexts right

Tags: asterisk, freepbx

In an asterisk dialplan, say one had:

```
[ext-miscdests]
include => ext-miscdests-custom
exten => 5,1,Noop(MiscDest: [some destination])
exten => 5,n,Goto(from-internal,[some number],1)
```

and wanted to squeeze in as the second step:

```
exten => 5,2,Log("NOTICE", "some notice")
```

how would one do that in context [ext-mistdests-custom]?

(this follows up on [How to use asterisk Include statement the right way?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29619049/how-to-use-asterisk-include-statement-the-right-way/77848884?noredirect=1#comment137244069_77848884))

Answer (score 0):

You should understand how asterisk do matching.

Asterisk does not rewrite rules in current context with include. It will APPEND rules.

So. If you have like this

```
[ext-miscdests]
include => ext-miscdests-custom
exten => 5,1,Noop(MiscDest: [some destination])
exten => 5,n,Goto(from-internal,[some number],1)
[ext-miscdests-custom]
exten => 5,1,Noop
```

that is equivalent of :

```
[ext-miscdests]
exten => 5,1,Noop(MiscDest: [some destination])
exten => 5,n,Goto(from-internal,[some number],1)
; includes append always AFTER direct lines.
exten => 5,1,Noop; this line will not work in most asterisk version due to already have same line
```

If you need override context, use *_ovveride*.conf files, not *_custom.conf files. Ovveride files added BEFORE other files in freepbx.